# Could these foundation defects cause problems?

Tags: walls, basement

Attached are the pictures of newly constructed basement wall. I wonder if these defects are going to be a problem in the future? Outside of the walls have water proofing, but I wonder if these defects will lead to problems with water leakage or structural issues.

Picture 1 - Honeycombing type effect - both side of door opening.
Picture 2 - line across the middle of the wall.
picture 3 - line across under the window and in the corner.
picture 4 - line in across the middle area

Are those type defects normal in the concrete walls?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Added a close request because it is not at all clear what you are asking. A bunch of pictures with no specific points highlighted does not give any clue as to what you are looking at.

Comment: I was asking those kind of basement walls are normal. As you can see in those pictures, there are some cracks and defective areas, some of them going across   the wall. I wonder those are normal in the concrete wall

Answer (score 1):

Well, these 'issues' so to speak are rather commonly seen on smaller construction sites (at my area of living) and are result of problems/mistakes while concrete laying. Probably all of them (as far as I can see from these pictures) are made by poor concrete thickening (without or with poor use of concrete vibrators or other devices). These, *ideally*, shouldn't be made by proffessionals, but they are still being seens here or there.
With proper water insulation these shouldn't cause trouble, **unless they are deep cracks** (concrete layered with too long interval and not thickened). Even if with cracks, structures are often over-designed for stress, so I doubt that it may cause any harm.
If I were You, I would rather look into proper and precise water insulation making - most often a real problem.
*(Correct my english, please, if needed)*

Comment: Thanks for your input. As you can see in the picture 1, they have black spry and then lay the water proofing material for out side walls. Do I need to consults any structural engineer to get second opinion on this?

Comment: @sam hi. well, I got hands-on experience with all of this You posted on pictures, so I'm just putting an answer based on given data (pictures + Your info) and my experience. the question of second opinion is one that I would not answer. I would just advise to supervise water insulation installation more srtictly.